# Unable to print the value of nullptr on screen

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading about `nullptr` and doing workout on g++ and also on VS2010.

When I did

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main(void)->int
{
    int j{};    
    int* q{};   

    cout << "Value of j: " << j << endl; // prints 0
    cout << nullptr << endl;
    cout << "Value of q: " << q << endl; // prints 0

    return 0;
}
```

printing the value of `nullptr` on screen, g++ and VS gave compiler error.
Is it not allowed to print the value of `nullptr` on screen?

Comment: What is **`int j{};`**?

Comment: uniform initialization syntax. Which will initialize j to 0.

Comment: Printing `nullptr` is simply useless, so why provide an ostream operator for `std::nullptr_t`? I think it's resonable to leave it out.

Comment: @stefan, it's useful in generic code where `nullptr_t` is a valid template parameter.

Comment: I wonder if its OK to provide an overload in the application's namespace for `nullptr_t`.. It would just return the `ostream` argument, doing nothing else...  anyone?

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2221

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.**

Type nullptr_t should be convertible to `T*`, but compiler has no `operator <<` for `nullptr_t` and don't know to which type you want to convert `nullptr`.

You can use this

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(nullptr) << endl;
```

Comment: nullptr is a literal, similar to true or false. We can print the value of true or false. Is there any standard which says, printing the nullptr will give compiler error?

Comment: @StackIT `true` and `false` are of type `bool` and are therefore printable. `nullptr` is of type `std::nullptr_t` and is therefore not printable.

Comment: @StackIT It is implied by the fact that the standard does not provide a `<<` overload for `std::nullptr_t`, but for arbitrary pointer types (`T*`), combined with the fact that the conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to an arbitrary pointer type is ambiguous, as the particular `T` cannot be determined by the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

This is because `nullptr` is of type `std::nullptr_t`, which does not define the appropriate operators for `std::cout` to be able print objects of that type. You can define the operator yourself like this:

```
//std::cout is of type std::ostream, and nullptr is of type std::nullptr_t
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::nullptr_t ptr)
{
    return os << "nullptr"; //whatever you want nullptr to show up as in the console
}
```

After this function is defined, it will be used to handle all attempts to print `nullptr` via an `ostream`. This way you don't need to cast `nullptr` every time you print it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding your own ostream operator for standard types is not allowed (at least without putting the operator<< in another namespace).

Comment: @Nevin Not allowed as in forbidden by the standard or not allowed as in frowned upon?

Comment: Forbidden by the standard: n3797 17.6.4.2.1 Namespace std [namespace.std]
1 The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Nevin In my example the operator was declared outside of any namespace. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Yes, I am 90% sure that is acceptable. I can't find the relevant section in the style guide right now, but I believe it is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while I was writing some type-parameterized test code (using templates). I needed to print a value of type `T`, where `nullptr_t` was a valid type for `T`. I came up with a solution where the value to be printed was wrapped inside a `printable` template function. This function then makes use of template specialization to provide the desired behavior when a `nullptr_t` is used.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct Printable
{
    Printable(const T& val) : val(val) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const {out << val;}
    const T& val;
};

template <> struct Printable<std::nullptr_t>
{
    Printable(nullptr_t) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const {out << "null";}
};

template <typename T>
Printable<T> printable(const T& value) {return Printable<T>(value);}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Printable<T>& p)
{
    p.print(out);
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << printable(42) << " " << printable(nullptr) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/9dcoL9)